# How to change dask job_name to SGECluster

Tags: dask, slurm, dask-distributed, sungridengine, dask-jobqueue

I am using `dask_jobqueue.SGECluster()` and when I submit jobs to the grid they are all listed as `dask-worker`. I want to have different names for each submitted job.

Here is one example:

```py
futures = []
for i in range(1,10):
    res = client.submit(slow_pow, i,2)
    futures.append(res)
    
[future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)]
```

All 10 jobs appear with name `dask-worker` when checking their status with `qsub`.

I have tried adding `client.adapt(job_name=f'job{i}')` within the loop, but no success, name still `dask-worker`.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

The `dask-worker` is a generic name for the compute allocation from the cluster, it can be changed by providing cluster-specific arguments at the time the cluster is created. For example, for SLURMCluster this would be:

```py
cluster = SLURMCluster('job_extra': ['--job-name="func"'])
```

SGECluster might have a different syntax.

The actual tasks submitted to `dask` scheduler will have their names generated automatically by `dask` and can be viewed through the dashboard, by default on (http://localhost:8787/status).

It's possible to specify a custom name for each task submitted to scheduler by using `key` kwarg:

```py
fut = client.submit(myfunc, my_arg, key='custom_key')
```

Note that if you are submitting multiple futures, you will want them to have unique keys:

```py
futs = [client.submit(myfunc, i, key=f'custom_key_{i}') for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I know I can change the default job name at cluster level. But this does not actually solve my problem. Is there a way to pass the future key and to assign it as the job name at cluster level?
Perhaps I should use the dashboard instead of the SGE `qstat` to check the status of the queue. I was expecting that there could be a possibility to add job name when submitting futures to the client.

Comment: AFAIK Once a cluster assigns a compute node, only cluster administrators can alter job properties (on the cluster), so dask (or dask jobqueue) won't be able to change the cluster job's name on the fly.

Comment: What dask can do is change the name of the tasks submitted to workers, but it seems that's not what you are looking for..